# C++ assembly function call pushes base pointer twice

Tags: c++, function, assembly, stack

Using Visual Studio, I have made a very simple Class in C++ called Watertank, which has a member function:

```
double Watertank::getcapacity() const{
    return capacity;
}
```

When I run the code:

```
Watertank wt = Watertank(100);
double capacity = wt.getcapacity();
```

the `double capacity = wt.getcapacity();` generates the following assembly:

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp, esp  
mov         ecx, 0F2E320h  
call        Watertank::getcapacity(0F21073h)  
fstp        qword ptr ds:[0F2E330h]  
cmp         ebp,esp  
call        _RTC_CheckEsp (0F250B0h)  
pop         ebp  
ret
```

And the assembly generated for the `double Watertank::getcapacity() const` body is:

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp,esp  
push        ecx  
mov         dword ptr [this],0CCCCCCCCh  
mov         dword ptr [this],ecx  
mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
fld         qword ptr [eax]  
mov         esp,ebp  
pop         ebp  
ret
```

Now, as I see it, when calling the `wt.getcapacity()` function, the base pointer is pushed onto the stack and the base pointer is updated to the current stack pointer. The function can then be executed, and the base pointer can be popped off the stack to return to the state before entering the function.

What I don't understand is why the function body also pushes a base pointer and pops it? I assume it has something to do with the use of the ecx register, but I don't know what that is used for.

Comment: The `push/pop ebp` probably belongs to the function where you called `wt.getcapacity` - i.e. it's the prologue/epilogue of that function. IIRC `ecx` is used to pass the `this` pointer when calling an instance method.

Comment: That explains it all, thank you very much!